# Script en linux que no se continuar sobre creación de sistema de archivos

Tags: linux, bash, script

Para una tarea me pidieron crear un sistema de archivos personalizado en la que el sistema va pidiendo y mostrando información:

- particiones disponibles
- partición elegida para el sistema de archivos
- ruta absoluta para montar el sistema de archivos
- mostrar de nuevo los sistemas de archivos en que se vea el creado

Llevo esto creado:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Creacción de un Sistema de Ficheros"

echo "Veamos la información completa de las particiones disponibles"
sudo lsblk -fm

echo "Ponga simplemente el nombre de la partición elegida, ignore la ruta (ejem.: sda1,   sdb3, sdc5)"
read unidad

echo "Elija el número correspondiente al tipo de sistema de archivos elegido"
    echo "Para sistema ext2 ........... ponga 2"
    echo "Para sistema ext3 ........... ponga 3"
    echo "Para sistema ext4 ........... ponga 4"
read sistema

echo "Elija un nombre de etiqueta para el Sistema de Ficheros"
read nombre

echo "El sistema de Ficheros ha sido creado con éxito"

echo "Para su información, nos encontramos en la siguiente ruta del sistema"
pwd

echo "Ponga a continuación la ruta absoluta con el directorio donde desea montar el Sistema de Ficheros"
read directorio
```

Alguien podría decirme alguna idea de como completar el ejercicio ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

por lo que veo en tu código, das la opción para elegir el sistema de archivos e imprimes en consola que lo has creado, pero no has realizado la acción

para ello podrías, después de:

```
echo "Elija un nombre de etiqueta para el Sistema de Ficheros"

read nombre
```

Agregar ésta parte de código

```
case $sistema in
2)
    sudo mkfs -t ext2 -L $nombre /dev/$unidad
    formato=2f
    ;;
3)
    sudo mkfs -t ext3 -L $nombre /dev/$unidad
    formato=3f
    ;;
4)
    sudo mkfs -t ext4 -L $nombre /dev/$unidad
    formato=4f
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac
```

En función de la elección del usuario, elige el sistema de archivos y con el case, se crea y se formatea según lo elegido

Pero ojo, aún faltaría montar el sistema y mostrarlo, el ejercicio puede llegar a ser extenso

**EDITADO**

A ver, para montar el sistema, podrías agregar despues de:

```
echo "Ponga a continuación la ruta absoluta con el directorio donde desea montar el Sistema de Ficheros"
read directorio
```

ésta parte de código

```
sudo mkdir $directorio

case $formato in
    2f)
        sudo mount -t ext2 /dev/$unidad /$directorio
        ;;
    3f)
        sudo mount -t ext3 /dev/$unidad /$directorio
        ;;
    4f)
        sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/$unidad /$directorio
        ;;
    *)
        ;;
esac

echo -e "Sistema de Archivos, con formato ext$formato\b, completado y montado con éxito en el directorio elegido: $directorio"
sleep 2

echo "Veamos ahora todos los Sistemas de Archivos Disponibles"
mount
```

En ésta última parte, según el sistema elegido en el punto anterior, se crea el directorio elegido y se monta el sistema de archivos en él.

Luego dejamos pasar dos segundos y mostramos los sistemas de archivos

y creo que estaría completo

Comment: Muchas gracias. Pero dices que aún habría que añadir mucho más código ?

Comment: Por lo que entiendo de la respuesta de @el.trasgu es que únicamente capturas información por parte del usuario, pero no haces nada con esa información. Esta respuesta utiliza lo que capturas para crear diversos formatos usando la herramienta `mkfs`

Comment: Pues a ver si lo estoy haciendo mal, lo que intento, es que en función del sistema elegido por el usuario del código que puso Gorka, en el case, hago el formato en ese sistema. Luego en la edición de mi respuesta, lo que hago es montarla. Es correcto ?

Comment: @el.trasgu Yo también entendí eso. Y parece que lo haces correctamente. Pero creo que eso sale sobrando por la pregunta de gorka

Comment: @el.trasgu, Por cierto. La opción `-L` de `mkfs` no lo encuentro en mi version de `mkfs`. En la tuya cómo aparece?

Comment: Vaya. Ya encontré eso pero no en el manual, sino probando. Que buen parámetro.

Comment: Hola Cuauhtli, perdona, estaba cenando. El parámetro -L sería para establecer el nombre del volumen creado del sistema de archivos si no recuerdo mal

Comment: Pues muchas gracias por las respuestas, aunque el código me queda muy grande, tendré que estudiarlo con mucha calma. Graciassss

Comment: @Gorka. Puedes evitar todo el código de los `case` tan sólo usando `mkfs -t "ext${sistema}" -L "$etiqueta" "$dispositivo"`

Comment: Gracias, lo pruebo también

Comment: Aquí tienes como se vería con las recomendaciones de @el.trasgu y mias: https://gitlab.com/mrc_es/stackoverflow_answers/-/tree/master/bash/454553